# How can I check if a String is an IP in Groovy?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

From a given String:

```
String someIp = // some String
```

How can I check, if someIp is a valid Ip format?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [InetAddressValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html) class to check and validate weather a string is a valid ip or not.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.routines.InetAddressValidator

...
String someIp = // some String
if(InetAddressValidator.getInstance().isValidInet4Address(someIp)){
    println "Valid Ip"
} else {
    println "Invalid Ip"
}
...
```

Try this..,.

Answer (score 3):

Regexes will do. There are simple ones and more complex. A simple one is this regex:

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Use it like this:

```
boolean isIP = someIP.maches("\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}");
```

But this will match 999.999.999.999 as well, which is not a valid IP address. There is a huge regex available on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html):

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

This one will take care of the job correctly. If you use this one, don't forget to escape every `\` with another `\`.

---

If you are not a fan of huge regexes, you can use this code:

```
public static boolean isIP(String str)
{
    try
    {
         String[] parts = str.split("\\.");
         if (parts.length != 4) return false;
         for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
         {
             int p = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
             if (p > 255 || p < 0) return false;
         }
         return true;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the superior answer, and he clearly knows REGEX in java better than I do, go with this one. I'm fairly new to the world of REGEX, and haven't used it in JAVA much yet.

Comment: Very good. Also, in Groovy, you can use `/regex/` string, thus not needing escapes, and use `==~` operator to check the regex match

Answer (score 1):

An oriented object way:

```
String myIp ="192.168.43.32"
myIp.isIp();
```

Known that , you must add this to **BootStrap.groovy**:

```
String.metaClass.isIp={
   if(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.routines.InetAddressValidator.getInstance().isValidInet4Address(delegate)){
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Use a validator like Apache's `commons-validator`:

```
@Grab('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.7')
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.InetAddressValidator

boolean isIpV4(String ip) {
    InetAddressValidator.instance.isValidInet4Address(ip)
}

isIpV4("8.8.8.8")
```

##### Or regex:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

class RegexValidationConstants {
    private final static String IPV4_OCT = /(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/
    final static Pattern IPV4 = ~/^${IPV4_OCT}(\.${IPV4_OCT}){3}$/.toString()
}

boolean isIpV4(String ip) {
    ip ==~ RegexValidationConstants.IPV4
}

isIpV4("8.8.8.8")
```

If you are using Grails, see [my answer in this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73814640/15016163).